# Rails: How to create a new entry in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, model-associations

Let's consider a practical example: A product that has many reviews, written by clients. We have a many-to-many relationship between *product* and *client* through *reviews*.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :clients, :through => :reviews
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :products, :through => :reviews
end

class Reviews < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :client
end
```

Here, I'm using the `has_many :through` to create the many-to-many relation, because the *review* table needs to have extra attributes, like the score, content, likes,...

The user logs into my app, so I can get his data through:

```
client = Client.find_by_id current_user.id
```

He goes to the product page, so I can get product data:

```
product = Product.find_by_id params[:id]
```

**How can I create client review of the product?**

I tried:

```
review = Review.create :client => client, :product => product, :comment => params[:review][:comment]
```

but it gives me: *MassAssignSecurity: can't mass-assign protected attributes: product, client*

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you create a Review object and explicitly pass arguments you need to make them accessible in your Review model. In this case it must be foreign keys

```
class Reviews < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :client

    attr_accessible :client_id, :product_id
end
```

That should work, but this's bad practice, which causes security issues. Instead of making foreign keys accessible and explicitly passing them in Review.create, I recommend to replace review.create with the following:

```
review = Review.new
review.client = client
review.product = product
review.comment = params[:review][:comment]
review.save
```

That will create a new Review object avoiding mass-assignment.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The :client and :product attributes are private, you have to make them accesible on each class setting `attr_accessible :client` and `attr_accessible :product` respectively like:

```
class Reviews < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :client

    attr_accessible :client, :product
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Vilem. As I wrote to prasad, it still doesn't work, even if I add `attr_accessible :product, :client` to the *Review* model.

Comment: I think you have to add attr_accessible to your classes, not in the model model.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please, can you be more precise, by updating your answer, using code, to explain which `attr_accessible :xxx` goes in which model `Xxx`?

Answer (score 0):

Add to ur model where the attributes are :product and :client

```
attr_accessible :product, :client
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply prasad, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work, even if I add `attr_accessible :product, :client` to the *Review* model. I'm using rails console (rails c) to make tests.

Comment: have you `reload!` after modifying model?